# Python re: how to set a limit to how many times a pattern is repeated

Tags: python, python-re

Say if I wanted a pattern to be repeated only until 5 times
how should I write the regex pattern?
I want to make it so that,
pattern repeated 1,2,3,4,5 times returns true,
pattern repeated 6 or more times returns false

```
pattern = re.compile("[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[,]")
 # This only catches one instance of the pattern

pattern = re.compile("[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[,])+ ")
# This catches one or more instance the pattern
```

Comment: Somwthing like **pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]{3}[,]){1,5}")** ?

Comment: please add test data and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole expression inside parenthesis and no. of repetition in curly braces after it. For example for 3 reputation it will be-
`pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]{3}[,])){3}")`

Answer (score 0):

Found out i can set a lower limit and upper limit to how many times an instance can be repeated

pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z0-9]{3}[,]){1,5}")